# print web page with F4 size with php/css/javascript/jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I want print my web page which the content is letter with paper's size F4 or Folio,but i have problem when print it in browser the web page always printed with A4/letter size. How to make it defaults to F4 or Folio so User not must setting again the paper size print setup ? anyways there is no setting for the size of F4 in my browser....

thanks for advance and this my code :

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Coba Print</title>   
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="screen.css" />  
    </head>            
    <body>
       ....here the letter
    </body>  </html>
```

Print.css

```
html{
    width: 8.5in;
    height: 13in;
}
body{ 
    width: 6.5in;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1in 1in 1in 1in;
    font-size: 12pt; 
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

screen.css

```
body{
    background: #aaa;
}
```

[image: NO F4 Size in browser setting]

Answer (score 1):

No, the Javascript object model includes a window.print() method that may activate the standard print dialogue of a Web browser, but that is as far as the functionality extends. It would not be appropriate or safe for Javascript code to be able to  look up printer properties or arbitrarily configure their settings.

I suggest to add a pop prior to printing where you remind the user to select the appropiate size.

Regarding the F4 size I don't have it either... it might be that is not supported by all printers, I suggest you pick a more common paper size , you can take a look at [this page](http://www.dpandi.com/paper/) to see the common ones.

Comment: But no F4 Size in browser setting... 
*like in image ^